# Display text with HTML tags

Tags: html, xamarin, webview, xamarin.android, label

I need to display `HTML` text on the page. Tryed to use WebView, but it can't fit `HTML` content height, it has only `HeightRequest`. I created renderer for `Label` to enable `HTML` tags in it.

```
public class HtmlLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
{

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);   
        Control?.SetText(Html.FromHtml(Element.Text), TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == Label.TextProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            Control?.SetText(Html.FromHtml(Element.Text), TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but when my `HTML` text has tag with `text-align:right`, `HtmlLabel` doesn't show it. When I use WebView, tags with `text-align:right` displays correctly.

How can I update `HtmlLabel` to display tags with `text-align:right` correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all HTML tags are supported by TextView.

According to [a Commonsware's blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) the following tags are supported:

```
<a href="...">
<b>
<big>
<blockquote>
<br>
<cite>
<dfn>
<div align="...">
<em>
<font size="..." color="..." face="...">
<h1>
<h2>
<h3>
<h4>
<h5>
<h6>
<i>
<img src="...">
<p>
<small>
<strike>
<strong>
<sub>
<sup>
<tt>
<u>
```

Although some inline css styles should work too. Make sure that your TextView is wide enough for the text to be displayed at the right edge.

Also according to this [unit test from google](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/master/tests/tests/text/src/android/text/cts/HtmlTest.java), the `text-align` should be `end` rather than `right`. Which works for `p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, div, blockquote`.